# Pourquoi jus et juteux ont-ils des orthographes incohérentes ?

Tags: étymologie, orthographe

Pourquoi écrit-on « le jus » ?

L'adjectif correspondant c'est « juteux ». Il serait donc logique d'écrire « le jut ».

Comment: You could ask this question about a thousand words in French, to lowball it. Or English. Why divine but divinity? Why not divinety? It's just different realizations / adaptations of original morphemes. Could ask at Linguistics SE for a more general answer.

Comment: L'orthographe française est tellement plus régulière que l'orthographe anglaise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Le nom *[jus](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/jus)* est la racine, pas l'adjectif.
L'épenthèse du *t*, c'est grâce à la phonologie et la morphologie, c'est la modification de la finale de la base.

> Du lat. jus, juris « jus, sauce, brouet ».

L'adjectif (et le nom) [juteux](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/juteux) est dérivé du mot *jus* avec le suffixe -eux, -euse et le *t* est une consonne épenthétique.  Cela aide à la prononciation mais ne sert à rien de sémantique.

> Dér. de jus*; suff. -eux*, avec -t- épenthétique.
>
> avec effacement de [R]

Il faut chercher le mot juste.  [CNRTL](https://cnrtl.fr/)

Comment: Donc ça ressemble à la dérivation « clou » ­- « [passage] clouté ». Pour celle-ci, le CNRTL donne la forme intermédiaire « clousté ». Peut-on donc imaginer qu'il y ait eu une forme intermédiaire « justeux » avant que ça devienne « juteux » ?

Comment: Probablement. Le mot *jus* s'est en fait lui-même aussi écrit *just* et *jeust* en ancien français.

Comment: Ça explique tout! Donc, probablement, à la fin du mot _just_ le t a disparu, tandis qu'à l'intérieur du mot, une autre transformation a eu lieu : _justeux_ est devenu _jûteux_ puis _juteux_.

Comment: Pareil avec le verbe *juter* qui était *jûser* et *jûter.*